# Receive ajax response in a website mvc

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

So I have 3 files now (a View, which consists of a list.js and list.php, and a Controller which consists of a get_data.php file).

get_data.php:

```
<?php
   $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $data = json_decode($str_json, true);
   $token = $data['token'];
   $request = $data['request'];
   echo "<p>" . $request . "</p>";
?>
```

list.js:

```
function getItems(list) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "../model/get_data.php";
  var dataPost = {"token" : true, "request": list};
  var str_json = JSON.stringify(dataPost);

  http.open("POST", url, true);

  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", dataPost.length);
  http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = http.responseText;
      }
  };
  http.send(str_json);
}

window.onload = getItems("start");
```

list.php:

```
<some html code>
<body>
   <span id="show" ></span>
</body>
<some more code>
```

I'm trying to implement the Model-View-Controller pattern, but I don't know how I'd transfer the 'echo' which is inside the 'get_data.php' file to the view.

Note that the `<span>` tag in the `list.php` file is the one showing the changing text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is just "include" your view into your controller via `require_once()` like this:

get_data.php:

```
<?php
    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($str_json, true);
    $token = $data['token'];
    $request = $data['request'];
    //echo "<p>" . $request . "</p>"; -- don't echo anything in the controller
    require_once('item.php');
?>
```

item.php:

```
<p>
  <?php echo $request ?>
</p>
```

`require_once()` will include the file just there so your scope doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, I know how the MVC works, but in this case this shouldn't be done like that, because this will only load the .js function once, when it should be load more than once.

Comment: Oh well, I see what you mean now. So the controller would just be for the items? Then I'd still need the `list.php` file containing the `<span>` tag, right?

Comment: Yes because your .js will just add stuff to your DOM and needs the `<span>` as a reference to decide where to put it (but you may rather change it into a `<div>` as `<span>` is for inline Text). 

side note: You may also think about creating a view object in php that receives some data and the name of a template file to have a more general approach on it.